# How to extract type from generic?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

How to extract first type from generic?

```
const App: FC<number> = () => { }

type FirstTypeFromApp = App[GET_FIRST_GENERIC] ??? // number
```

how to extract generic type `number` from `App`, how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Infer to do it.

```
type FC<T> = () => any;
const App: FC<number> = () => { };

type extractGeneric<Type> = Type extends FC<infer X> ? X : never;

type FirstTypeFromApp = extractGeneric<typeof App>;


const x: FirstTypeFromApp = 13221; //String will throw error
```

Here is the playground: [playgoround](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgwgHgCoD4oF4oAoCUG0CGAdiANwCwAUAMYD2RAzsFAIJhgBcsiRArgLYAjCACc0mXPigBvKAF8KlKqEhQIAD2AiC1YAHEIRUQEtqycBHFQkFtZsMATBtwTGiAM1FQAGmgD8PlBcRgBuoorKtjDGIkw2kDAitPxsYBh2Wjr6hiZmKhC07qzsKBFKNPRMUOpc0bHA8RCJyanpAIwAzABMXW2kUAD0AwDKWm4A5lAA7sYANrNQwAAWSVNqIkkiQA)