# How to extract generic type in interface or typeof type in Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics, typeof

I'm trying to use generics and interface to make React component.

```
interface MyAtomComponent {
  <P>(props: P): React.ReactElement;
  WithSomeOption: <P>(props: P): React.ReactElement;
}

// component definition
const MyAtomComponent: MyAtomComponent = <P,>(props: P) => { ... };
MyAtomComponent.WithSomeOption = <P,>(props: P) => { ... };

// in use
<MyAtomComponent<{/* something */}> />
<MyAtomComponent.WithSomeOption<{/* something */}> />
```

It looks good, but problem occurs in this case:

```
type MoleculeProps = {/* molecule prop */} & MyAtomComponent['WithSomeOption'] // Generic of WithSomeOption is gone

const Molecule = ({...}: MoleculeProps<number>) => { ... }; // I cannot put `number` because MoleculeProps is not generic
```

I tried like this:

```
type AtomPropsWithGeneric = MyAtomComponent['WithSomeOption'];
// AtomPropsWithGeneric is now <P>(props: P): React.ReactElement

const Test: AtomPropsWithGeneric<{}> = ... // AtomPropsWithGeneric is not generic.
```

and also this failed too:

```
type AtomPropsWithGeneric<P> = MyAtomComponent['WithSomeOption']<P>; // ';' expected
```

I think `[]` in type cannot extract generic; `typeof` also print same error(`';' expected`).

Is any way to extract generic type in interface?

---

stack overflow suggested [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68465176/how-to-extract-type-from-generic) but I think this case is little bit different.

Comment: If you move the generic up to `MyAtomComponent<P>` itself rather than just its members then it seems it would address at least some of your concerns. Do you need further explanation?

Comment: Defining react components as generic functions doesn't make sense since the type on a generic function is defined by the caller, and _you don't ever call react component functions, the framework does_.

What are you actually trying to achieve by making them generic?

Comment: Does this question depend on React? If so then please tag it as such (or I will, if you don't mind).  If not then please [edit] the code to be a [mre] that doesn't seem to depend on third-party frameworks.

Comment: Are you looking for [this](https://tsplay.dev/WvkGQw)?

Comment: @jcalz
I thought this question is depend on React(because the purpose of this is to make React component expendable without optional props). So I added `react` tag. Thank you!

Comment: @BenWainwright
Thank you but I apologize that I couldn't understand because I cannot speak English as well.
The acheive what I want using generic is to fix the data type and callback type in caller.
Could this be the answer that you're asking?

Comment: @motto
Thank you, but the purpose of this generic is to define generics in use, not in definition. I added some definition.

Comment: @jcalz Sorry I thought the purpose of this question is to solve my React problem, but I felt the answer is close to typescript. Should I change example code?

Comment: If you want to make it more general you can do so, but it's fine to leave it tagged with react

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [instantiation expressions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-7.html#instantiation-expressions) ([#47607](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47607)):

```
type WithSomeOption<P> = typeof MyAtomComponent.WithSomeOption<P>;
```

It's very important to use dotted access instead of bracket notation, as the latter will not parse:

```
// not valid TS
type WithSomeOption<P> = typeof MyAtomComponent["WithSomeOption"]<P>;
```

We also need `typeof` since dotted access on interfaces is disallowed (or else it could be mistaken for a namespace):

```
// will error; "Cannot access 'MyAtomComponent.WithSomeOption' because 'MyAtomComponent' is a type, but not a namespace."
type WithSomeOption<P> = MyAtomComponent.WithSomeOption<P>;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4BYAKCuADsYkpN0k4BZATwEEZcBhXJFpJ6cAN5U4cADwAFAHwAKMDjABnAFxxZASi3J0MAHQGMAUQA2SECJgVKUgOrAYACwDKuJAHkwMYBC0WnJKKhDqWrpwALzyiMTGpjCW1rb2AL5UVAAmSGgWKERwaIFq8Jw8-IKBtloVvCAC4DX09lQA9O1wdHAArmpIVNL1Vc3C9NJi7QBUcGpebnQA5nDT7elx7fL2w9wNTUK2Rs5unja+-oGTM3MLrsur65vbWZQwHGCsJx5eFwG0IRicHenwgmHYe1Gh3oxxcP3Ofn+IVIQA)

Comment: Thank you so much, this is definitely what I want!